# I'm not able add any item into cart with two store in one installation

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

I have a magento site that has two store in it. Retail and wholesale.

I'm not able to add any item to the cart it shows blank page.

The error is this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Weee_Helper_Data::setStore() in /var/www/vhosts/club27clothing.com/club27clothing.com/app/code/core/Mage/Weee/Model/Total/Quote/Weee.php on line 93
```

Compilation is disabled, cache cleared and refreshed.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Can you check your file app/code/core/Mage/Weee/Model/Total/Quote/Weee.php against the default of that version, I think you have custom changes in it.

Comment: thanks. I fixed it. the problem was a version differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file or module is different in 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 I manually uploaded some core files by mistake and I turned back to 1.8.0 as it was before it fixed the problem.

Comment: Please mark this answer as solution!